# Ms Chart in WPF .Net 4.0 App not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, mschart

I have been able to get other Form controls to work in WPF, but I can't seem to get a Chart control to show itself as anything other than a white rectangle.

I have tried using a WindowsFormsHost in XAML

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="4">
    <dv:Chart x:Name="chart"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

I have also created a `UserControl`

```
public partial class ChartUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ChartUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createSomethingToSee();
    }

    private void createSomethingToSee()
    {
        chart.Series.Clear();
        var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
        {
            Name = "Series1",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        };

        this.chart.Series.Add(series1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        { series1.Points.AddXY(i, i); }
        chart.Invalidate();
    }      
}
```

In my window I use both methods and nothing is displaying

```
<my:ChartUserControl  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  x:Name="chartUserControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<my:MyChart Grid.Row="1" Height="249" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" x:Name="myChart1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="633" />
```

Has anyone had any luck using Chart in WPF? Is it possible? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to use winform chart in wpf control? You can also use wpf toolkit chart which is free and easy to use.

Comment: @MKMohanty - I started playing with wpf toolkit chart but couldn't really find much documentation on it. Do you have any links for documentation?

Comment: wpf toolkit chart is useful when you know that the number of points you're going to add to the series is small in number. It chokes up when you add more than a few thousand points in. MS-Chart (earlier dundas chart) is extremely robust, fast and doesn't choke up even if you add hundreds of thousands of points in.